# How is tomcat memory displayed by the system?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7, ram

I gave my tomcat about 3Gb of ram on a virtual machine that has around 8GB,
-Xms3072M -Xmx3072M -Xmn1024M.

after I start tomcat and typed in the terminal

" ps -eo pmem,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -10"

the answer I get for the first and only java process is  19.4% 
(19.4 7052620 12748 /usr/bin/java...)
My question is what is this 19.4% is it the ram memory of tomcat without the heap?
this is the equation i found online:

Max memory = [-Xmx] + [-XX:MaxPermSize] + number_of_threads * [-Xss] (https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx)

because 19.4% of 8GB is 2 GB, and my heap is 3 GB. is this the ram memory without the heap?

Comment: That young generation size seems excessive. Why do you want your young generation to be 1/3 the size of your whole heap?

Comment: I am QA doing performance testing in a startup, the setup was used to get better performance.I found this online :                                                      By default, the Application Server is invoked with the Java HotSpot Server JVM. The default NewRatio for the Server JVM is 2: the old generation occupies 2/3 of the heap while the new generation occupies 1/3. The larger new generation can accommodate many more short-lived objects, decreasing the need for slow major collections. The old generation is still sufficiently large enough to hold many long-lived objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't name your OS, though it's fairly obvious it's a *NIX-type OS.

The memory that `ps` shows is real, allocated memory. It will include all "native", heap, and `mmap`ed memory that has been allocated to your process. If your process is very young (i.e. hasn't been running very long), then it will not have used very much of its heap, yet.

Many OSs, most notably Linux, will allow [malloc to return success](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) even if physical memory is not actually allocated. Since the JVM allocates your `-Xms` setting immediately upon startup, you'd likely expect that your process's memory size would be *at least* 3072MiB, but if that memory isn't actually being used, then `ps` will likely show a smaller size than you expect.

If you are indeed using Linux, check out https://serverfault.com/questions/48582 and do a bit of web searching for exactly how the Linux kernel allocates memory. Also, if you *are* using Linux, consider adding the `linux` tag to your question.

If you are *not* using Linux, you may want to read about how your OS allocates memory. If your OS uses an "overcommit" strategy, then it will behave as described above.